# ClientProtocolException in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am new to testing and using the jmeter for the first time. Using [these steps](http://www.360logica.com/blog/2015/12/how-to-configure-jmeter-and-mobile-device-to-record-scripts-for-native-app-in-it.html) I am trying to record the mobile device scripts in jmeter. I have done the following steps:

1. Open JMeter and right-click the TestPlan>Add >Threads (Users)>Thread Group.
2. Right-click the Thread group>Add>Logic Controller>Recording Controller.
3. Right-click the Threads>Add>Listener>View Results Tree.
4. Add test script recorder by selecting Add>Non-Test Elements>HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder option.
5. Add ‘8080’ as Port value and click the Start button. This will start the JMeter proxy on localhost.

but when I am checking the server status on browsers (`https://localhost:8080`), following error comes:

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: https:////
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:817)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:240)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be opening `https://localhost:8080` URL in browser, you need to configure your mobile device to use the machine, where JMeter is running as proxy host and 8080 as a proxy port.

If you want to test the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - configure you browser to use `localhost` as a proxy host and `8080` as a proxy port and open some intranet or Internet page - you should see the requests under the Recording Controller.

You quickly set up JMeter for recording using [Templates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) feature, just choose `File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create` from JMeter's main menu and you will have JMeter ready for recording in a couple of seconds (default proxy port will be `8888` in this setup)

If you are targeting to record HTTPS traffic on a mobile device you will also need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto it. Look for `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in JMeter's bin folder, send it to yourself via the email, open the email on mobile device and follow your mobile OS dialog to get it installed.

See [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for more information on proper recording of mobile devices traffic using JMeter